# In Scala, is there a way to access a symbol (variable) defined in an outer scope?

Tags: scala

For example:

```
def factory(_name: String) = new Person {
    val name: String = _name
}
```

I'm looking to avoid mangling the name of `_name` in the outer scope.

Comment: @pst, I meant: since `name` is part of interface of method `factory`, it should not be mangled, but rather a local variable should be introduced as in your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While far from an ideal approach, this "does the trick":

```
abstract class Person { val name: String }
def factory(name: String) = {
   val _name = name
   new Person {
     val name: String = _name
   }
}
factory("Fred").name // Fred
```

I don't know of any other way to get close. There is a section in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (Chapter 2) which talks about shadowing -- and in no place does it discuss a way to qualify those "implicit" scopes.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you. Have you seen this little trick I stumbled upon? Within a function, suppose you want to use a parameter implicitly, but you don't want to declare the parameter as implicit in your function signature. You can do `implicit val _ = x' (where x is the name of the function parameter).